# Mod rewrite not working on apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I work on apache2 server. I am trying to display webpages on my website without the file extension .php using the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----

ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

IndexIgnore *
```

It is simply not working. I still see my webpages with .php extension in my browser.

I have mod rewrite module loaded and also I made changes in apache2.conf file as follows:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also my .htaccess file is doing other jobs (i.e. redirecting the 404 to filenotfound.php ) without any problem. So why is this rewrite rule not working? How can I possibly debug the .htaccess file?

Comment: debug your htaccess with: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ edit, ah Request Filename not supported atm - but great tool for general debug questions.

Answer (score 0):

> I still see my webpages with .php extension in my browser.

Well you don't even have a rule to redirect a request with `.php` to a URL without it.

Have your rules as this:

```
# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----    
ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----    
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is now showing the url without the file extension. :) But it is saying filenotfound. So what I want is when I open /dir/file.php the browser shows the url as /dir/file but it still shows the actual /dir/file.php. I am very confused here.

Comment: This code already does both. Just make sure this code is placed in `DocumentRoot` not in any sub-directory.

Comment: Well it is only doing half of the task for me. I tried removing the last part of your code and it still does that half task(i.e rewriting the url without .php) But after that it is trying to find a file with .html extension i.e it is looking for /dir/file.html to show and when if it is not there then 404 is coming. So, can we make it find /dir/file.php instead of /dir/file.html

Comment: Where did you see .html in my rules?

Comment: In fact you can even keep last rule as you showed in your question, in place of the last rule where I am adding .php in the URL.